# What happens if a websocket processes messages slower than the rate at which they're received?

Tags: websocket

What happens if a client takes longer to process messages then the rate at which messages come in?

Let me write to dummy code to illustrate what I'm trying to ask

```py
async def process(message):
    """Process one message, may take up to 1000ms"""
    # some actual work would happen here
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())


async def process_stream(address):
    """Process all messages as they arrive"""
    async with websockets.connect(address) as websocket:
        # expect one message every 100ms
        async for message in websocket:
            # process each message for up to 1000ms
            await process(message)

asyncio.run(process_stream("wss://place-of-interest"))
```

In this case we are receiving messages at a rate 10x higher than we process. Processing will occasionally or even regularly fall behind as new messages are supposed to arrove.

Are websockets implemented/guaranteed to have some cache for messages until the application is ready to process them? Obviously if this was a real application this would be problematic but what if occasionally it takes longer to process a message than the rate at which they get sent? Can messages get dropped in this manner?

(in case a concrete websocket implementation is desired, I'm working with the `tokio-tungstenite` implementation of a websocket)

Comment: Why is your example code a mix of Python and Rust?

Comment: a server should always check that the socket it want to write to is not full, that basic server rule, if you try to write on a full socket the os with make your server wait. The detail on how manage this are too broad to be answer.

Comment: It's a high level implementation question, I reference rust just to give a concrete example if it mattered (which it didn't) and the code is only meant for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websockets are a high-level protocol over [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), which includes a [flow control mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) that reduces the transmission rate if the server can't keep up. Basically:

- The OS on the server keeps a buffer for the incoming bytes. If your server is too slow, this buffer fills up and eventually overflows.
- When the server buffer overflows, the OS stops acknowledging incoming TCP packets, which causes the TCP flow control mechanism to kick in and reduce the transmission rate.
- The OS on the client also keeps a buffer for the outgoing bytes. When the transmission rate is reduced, this buffer fills up and eventually overflows.
- When the client buffer overflows, attempting to write to the socket will either block until there is space in the buffer (causing the client application to pause) or return an `E_WOULDBLOCK` error allowing the client application to handle the slowdown.

Note that in case of the occasional glitch, the client and server buffers are usually enough to smooth things over until the application catches up.

Comment: Does this mean that a server has to make a web socket for every machine that connects to it? I imagined that a server sent the same message to all clients that bind to it but this sounds like the server can determine how fast client is able to receive messages and can change how it send messages accordingly (like if it's sending changes about the state of an object too quickly than it could aggregate the state changes and send them less frequently)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the server has to make a web socket for every machine". The server needs to call [`accept`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.2/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.accept) for each client, and this call to `accept` does create a new TCP socket. And yes if the server wants to broadcast a message to all clients it will need to write this message to each client socket, which may cause issues if one of the clients is too slow and the corresponding socket blocks.